# Paste multiple lines before a line in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

How do I copy multiple lines and paste them as a block before a line? As an example I have the following code and I want to copy and paste the three lines after the if statement to after the else statement but before the line below it.

```
[row col] = find(H);  
if (nargin < 4)    

    delqmn = sparse(row, col, 0, M, N); % diff of msgs from bits to checks
    delrmn = sparse(row, col, 0, M, N);% diff of msgs from checks to bits
    rmn0 = sparse(row, col, 0, M, N);% msgs from checks to bits (p=0)
else

// Insert 3 lines after if statement here

qn0 = 1-r;% pseudoposterior probabilities
qn1 = r;% pseudoposterior probabilities
```

Thanks

Comment: This is basic stuff and is covered in the `vimtutor`. I suggest you run it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a lot of useful information from vim itself with

```
:help registers
```

Briefly, to copy multiple lines use: `#yy`  where # is the number of lines to copy

To paste those lines use `P` to paste above the cursor and `p` to paste below.

If you copy each line at a time (by doing `yy` three times), you will copy text into three registers.  In order to paste the lines back in, you can paste from each of these registers with "#p (where # is the register number).  This is a good method if the copied text isn't in a contiguous block.

Comment: Umm, I think you misunderstand how "`p`" works. If a register is not specified, it will _always_ paste the unnamed register (`"`).  So pressing `p` three times will give you three copies of the _last_ line yanked, unless the user deliberately says otherwise.

Comment: oic.  I was sure it cleared 0 and moved 1 into 0 and ". will edit

Comment: Almost there. You have to prefix the register name with a `"` character, otherwise it's treated as a count.  For example, `5p` will paste the unnamed register five times, while `"5p` will paste the numbered register 5.

Comment: As I recommended to the OP, you might want to run through the `vimtutor` if you haven't already.

Comment: @Heptite oops, typo. thx.  where's your answer

Comment: You covered it pretty well, and since I have nothing significant to add I don't want to "karma snipe."

Answer (score 0):

As Heptite already wrote, this is basic stuff. `vimtutor` rules.

In case you are curious, here are a few slightly "advanced" ways to do what you want. Assuming your cursor is on the first line of the block you want to duplicate and you have `set number`, all of the methods below lead to the same result. It's of course possible to combine their individual parts to suit your needs, this is *far* from being an exhaustive list.

```
3yy/els<cr>p
    3yy      yank 3 lines starting with the current one
    /els<cr> position the cursor on else
    p        put the content of the default register after the cursor

y2j7Gp
    y2j      yank until 2 lines below
    7G       move the cursor to line 7
    p        put the content of the default register after the cursor

3yy}P
    3yy      yank 3 lines starting with the current one
    }        place the cursor on the next blank line        
    P        put the content of the default register before the cursor

V2j:t+3
    V2j      visually select linewise until 2 lines below
    :        enter command-line mode, a range is inserted for you
    t+3      copy the selected lines after line (current line + 3)

:4,6t7
    :        enter command-line mode
    4,6      the line numbers of the block you want to copy, see :help range
    t7       copy those lines after line 7
```